# Dynamic array from 3 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have array with 2 constant elements

```
$this->Properties = array(
"ConstName1"   => $ConstVal_1, "ConstName2"   => $ConstVal_2
);
```

How add to this array dynamic elements (names elements) from another array

```
$this->Names = array(
"DynName1"   => $Name_1, "DynName2"   => $Name_2
);
```

and put to this elements values from 3 array

```
$this->Values = array(
"DynVal1"   => $Val_1, "DynVal2"   => $Val_2
);
```

Finaly: I tried get $Name_1 from second array /as Name/ and $Val_1 from third array /as value/, then combine /$Name_1=>$Val_1/ and add to first array

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you need `array_merge()`? Question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: You have to use array_combine.

Comment: It sounds like it may be the `array_merge()` function you'd need to use - but I'm not certain from your question what the final output/array you're looking for is...

Could you edit your question/comment with the desired final array structure/contents confirmed?

Comment: $this->Properties = array(
"ConstName1"   => $ConstVal_1, "ConstName2"   => $ConstVal_2, $Name_1 => $Val_1, $Name_2 => $Val_2
);

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Properties = array_merge(
    array("ConstName1"   => $ConstVal_1, "ConstName2"   => $ConstVal_2),
    array("DynName1"   => $Name_1, "DynName2"   => $Name_2),
    array("DynVal1"   => $Val_1, "DynVal2"   => $Val_2)
);
```

Or:

```
$this->Properties = array();

$this->Properties = array_merge(
    $this->Properties,
    array("ConstName1"   => $ConstVal_1, "ConstName2"   => $ConstVal_2)
);

$this->Properties = array_merge(
    $this->Properties,
    array("DynName1"   => $Name_1, "DynName2"   => $Name_2)
);

$this->Properties = array_merge(
    $this->Properties,
    array("DynVal1"   => $Val_1, "DynVal2"   => $Val_2)
);
```

Or even:

```
$this->Properties = array();

$this->Properties["DynVal1"] = $Val_1;
$this->Properties["DynVal2"] = $Val_2;
// and so on
```

Comment: Thanks Havenard, but I tried get $Name_1 from second array /as Name/ and $Val_1 /as value/ from third array, then combine /$Name_1=>$Val_1/ and add to first array...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You want to give the keys dynamic names? Seems like you having the wrong concept about something.